# last time procedure executed in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

Is it possible to know when a stored procedure was last executed?  I'm using Oracle 11g.

I've got an old app that has many years of procedures in it.  The goal is to quickly identify candidates for retirement.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing in the data dictionary that records when a package/procedure/function was last executed.

If you have candidates for deletion, you could `AUDIT EXECUTE BY SESSION` on those, using the `DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL` data dictionary view to prune the list over time -- and `NOAUDIT EXECUTE` those objects which get used.

Comment: thanks for these suggestions.  I'm not familiar with these settings, so will take a look.